# React Native - State Changing but Component is not re-rendering

Tags: react-native, state, render

I am making a menu for changing the type of the Google Maps API but the state pressed is not working as I intended. Note that state inside the Text component is not being re-rendered after `this.state.pressed` is changed on the function `setPressedState` and it is not re-rendering on the component that contains `MapMenu` component after using `getPressed`.

**Note:** the Alert shows that state pressed is being changed.

```
class MapMenu extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pressed: 'standard'
        }
    }

    setPressedState(press){
        this.state.pressed = press;
        Alert.alert(this.state.pressed)
    }

    getPressed(){
        return(this.state.pressed);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}><Text>{this.state.pressed}</Text></View>

                <TouchableOpacity   style={styles.button}
                                    onPress={() => this.setPressedState('standart')}
                >
                    <Text>Mapa</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity   style={styles.button}
                                    onPress={() => this.setPressedState('hybrid')}
                >
                    <Text>Hibrido</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity   style={styles.button}
                                    onPress={() => this.setPressedState('satellite')}
                >
                    <Text>Satellite</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: use `this.setState(key,value)` to re-render the components

Answer (score 5):

To re-render component, you'll need to use `setState` method, as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state), that says:

> In general, you should initialize state in the constructor, and then call setState when you want to change it.

See this,

```
setPressedState = (press) => {
    this.setState({pressed:press}, () => {
      Alert.alert(this.state.pressed)
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the correct method. Adding on to the answer is the link to the doc
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way that you are doing , you should not take state as any other variables you use and use assignment operator ,

In react for variables and constants you can use assignment operator,
But In case of a state you should use.

```
setState({
stateVariable:NewValue 
})
```